# I have deployed my django project in python anywhere but its not working

Tags: django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I have deployed my website in [Python Anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) but its not working. I have uploaded it to python anywhere, also changed WSGI and settings.py but it is just showing [welcome page.](http://rahulsatal.pythonanywhere.com/).

**setting.py file on server**

```
 # Django settings for website project.
    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

    ADMINS = (
        # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
    )

    MANAGERS = ADMINS
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'django_db',
            'USER': 'rahulsatal',
            'PASSWORD': 'rahul',
            'HOST': '',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
    '''
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
    '''
    # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

    # Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
    # although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
    # On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
    # timezone as the operating system.
    # If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
    # system time zone.
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

    # Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
    # http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    SITE_ID = 1

    # If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
    # to load the internationalization machinery.
    USE_I18N = True

    # If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
    # calendars according to the current locale
    USE_L10N = True

    # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/rahulsatal/website/media'

    # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
    # trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/rahulsatal/website/static'

    # URL prefix for static files.
    # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
    # Make sure to use a trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

    # Additional locations of static files
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    )

    # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
    # various locations.
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    )

    # Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
    SECRET_KEY = '-k$4lu9+wnz&nbnij!c8+f*ltoebjpn97^xu%ofra+)&5aa7vm'

    # List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        # 'django.contrib.admin',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
        # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
        'website',
    )

    # A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
    # performed by this configuration is to send an email to
    # the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
    # more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'handlers': {
            'mail_admins': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        }
    }
```

**WSGI file on server**

```
"""
WSGI config for website project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""
import sys
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'website.website.settings'


sys.path.append('/home/rahulsatal/website')
# ...
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'website.settings'
```

**and my error log are-**

```
2015-02-26 22:02:05,989 :IOError: write error
2015-02-26 22:02:05,990 :RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
2015-02-27 10:44:57,526 :/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py:1160: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
2015-02-27 10:44:57,526 :  return _active[_get_ident()]
2015-02-27 10:44:57,527 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-27 10:44:57,527 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
2015-02-27 10:44:57,527 :    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
2015-02-27 10:44:57,527 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in exception
2015-02-27 10:44:57,541 :    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,541 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
2015-02-27 10:44:57,541 :    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,542 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
2015-02-27 10:44:57,542 :    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,542 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in makeRecord
2015-02-27 10:44:57,542 :    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,542 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in __init__
2015-02-27 10:44:57,542 :    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
2015-02-27 10:44:57,542 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
2015-02-27 10:44:57,543 :    return _active[_get_ident()]
2015-02-27 10:44:57,543 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
2015-02-27 10:44:57,543 :    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,543 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
2015-02-27 10:44:57,554 :    self.load_middleware()
2015-02-27 10:44:57,554 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
2015-02-27 10:44:57,562 :    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
2015-02-27 10:44:57,562 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
2015-02-27 10:44:57,564 :    self._setup()
2015-02-27 10:44:57,564 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
2015-02-27 10:44:57,616 :    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,616 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 90, in __init__
2015-02-27 10:44:57,616 :    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,616 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2015-02-27 10:44:57,617 :    __import__(name)
2015-02-27 10:44:57,617 :  File "./website/settings.py", line 33
2015-02-27 10:44:57,617 :    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
2015-02-27 10:44:57,617 :                ^
2015-02-27 10:44:57,617 :SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2015-02-27 10:44:59,352 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-27 10:44:59,352 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
2015-02-27 10:44:59,352 :    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
2015-02-27 10:44:59,352 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in exception
2015-02-27 10:44:59,352 :    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,352 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
2015-02-27 10:44:59,352 :    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,353 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
2015-02-27 10:44:59,353 :    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,353 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in makeRecord
2015-02-27 10:44:59,353 :    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,353 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in __init__
2015-02-27 10:44:59,353 :    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
2015-02-27 10:44:59,353 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :    return _active[_get_ident()]
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :    self.load_middleware()
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
2015-02-27 10:44:59,354 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :    self._setup()
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 90, in __init__
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :    __import__(name)
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :  File "./website/settings.py", line 33
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :                ^
2015-02-27 10:44:59,355 :SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please anybody help me out.

Answer (score 2):

1.Try: 
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['rahulsatal.pythonanywhere.com']`

2. Active your virtualenv by updating WSGI file

```html
activate_this = '/home/harunbiswas/.virtualenvs/django18/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), activate_this, 'exec')
    exec(code, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error log that you posted may not apply because errors like that would mean you'd see the "Something went wrong" page. Also, I think your WSGI file may be OK (again since you are seeing a welcome page and not an error page). The thing that you should check is that you are running the code that you think you are running. Are the urls and views in the directory that you WSGI file is pointing to the ones that you expect to see there?

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` set the following option

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
```

Comment: Can you explain why adding that configuration value will help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Python / Django - Free Hosting

Hosting Steps

1.Server exit - ctrl+C press

2.`pip freeze > requirements.txt` //this will create a file requirements.txt to our project that show all of our installed python libraries used in our project

3.In vs code, right click our root project folder containing src and venv .
click ‘reveal in file explorer’ or shift+alt+R or open our root folder.

Then right click project folder in src.click ‘add to projectname.rar’ //compress to rar file.

This file will be uploading to host the django project

4.Go to pythonanywhere.com

Sign up

Create a beginner account

Go to dashboard- click files - upload a file-then uload our ‘projectname.rar’ file

Go to dashboard - click consoles - new console - click bash - this will open a terminal in browser

Type pwd in cmd shows our current folder

Type ls to show current files in the folder

Type `unrar x projectname.rar` //to unzip our project file

If it is zip file , then type unzip x projectname.zip

ls - shows our project folder

cd projectname/

ls - shows our files like manage.py,requirements.txt,..

Three lines right side, click help, django deploy , copy paste below code,

Type `mkvirtualenv –python=/usr/bin/python3.8 venv` //this will create virtual env

5.`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Three lines right side, right click web - open in new tab- add new web app
Click next- click manual configuration under select a framework

Select python version- click next // shows a browser showing our web address

Right click configuration ‘ourwebname’ -open in new tab // this will be our website

Click files - in navigation bar- open the folder containing manage.py - copy the path

Go to website setup page - paste the path into source code under code

Copy paste the path to venv also like the previous procedure

Then you can see , wsgi under code //scroll to see code,source code, wsgi,....

Click the path link of wsgi configuration file. Then delete all the codes below and above the django code part.
Then uncomment
Uncomment import os, import sys, path ,....

6.Rewrite the path code with our projectname instead of mysite

Rewrite projectname.settings

Then save. Click back

In our main page, click reload our webpage link

Then open our webpage in new tab.
It will show error like disallowed host

So go to files, open settings.py, change code allowed hosts - website name without https and last slash.
Just need ‘websitename.com’ // use single quotes.
Click save, back
Click web under navigation bar, then click reload our site

7.If it shows an error like template doesn’t exist, then go to settings.py , then change the code to , TEMPLATES=[
{
…………
`‘DIRS’ : [BASE_DIR/’templates’]` . then click save.
Then click reload under web-navigation bar. Now we can see our project website
If the css is not working, click web in navigation bar, scroll down to see the static files url .to get static files url.

Click files in navigation bar, copy paste the path of static folder. Under url type ‘ /static/’ //same as in settings file .
under directory paste the url of static .

In settings.py file,

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR/’static’
STATIC_URL = ‘static/’
```

Comment or delete ,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join………
]
```

Open command prompt window in browser,

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Type yes to allow rewriting

Then reload under web -navigation bar. Then open our site in browser. It will load our project with css

Now your django project is on live!!!!!

Happy hosting :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to add `'localhost'` or `'*'` to the allowed hosts - else nobody will be able to access your pages.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('localhost')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but i want to deploy it on https and still not working

Comment: https is nothing to do with the allowed hosts. If you want to use https, please look into installing an SSL-Certificate.

Comment: now on using * ---Something went wrong :-(        is displayed

Comment: make sure it reads the exact same as this;

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('*')`

Comment: Equally, just use this (taken from my Django env)

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    'localhost'
)`

Comment: Again Welcome page appeared

Comment: You haven't setup any URLs, as the message on screen dictates.

Comment: I think it should be `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`, no?  Putting the list of hosts in round brackets won't put it in a tuple unless you put a comma after the string.  And IMO lists look prettier than tuples :-)